# How to remove specific xml node using DOMDocument when multiple childNodes exist?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

The standard way to remove a node using PHP's DOMDocument is:

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($node);
$dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
```

The problem arises when there are multiple child nodes, as this method will simply delete the first child. For example XML generated by the Google Contacts API, which looks basically like this:

```
<phoneNumber>
    <first number node>
    <second number node>
    <etc...>
</phoneNumber>
```

So the question is, how can I remove a specific node within the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SimpleXML is Object-Orientated, simply use

```
unset($xml->node)
```

to delete, then

```
$xml->saveXML();
```

to save.